# How to fetch data from database if one model has relation with two models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch data from database using Laravel eloquent but it returns no data. Here is the database structure

- Region

  - id
  - name
- District

  - id
  - name
  - region_id
- Ward

  - id
  - name
  - region_id

So the ward doesn't relate with district it relates with Region. How can I get ward(data)? This is how I fetch data

```
Area::with('region.district.ward')->get();
```

Models

Region.php

```
public function district()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(District::class);
    }

public function ward()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Ward::class);
   }
```

District.php

```
public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }
```

Ward.php

```
public function regions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }
```

Comment: May be you want something like `Region::with('district')->with('ward')->get();`

Comment: If  I use that, what if I have `Area::with('region.district.ward')->get();` how do i get `ward` ? @EsTeAa

Comment: In this way  `Area::with('region.ward')->get();` or together `Area::with(['region.district','region.ward'])->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the descendant tables by using **dot** notation, when you have data like a chaining structure,  like `table2` => `table2` => `table 3`

```
Model1::with('model2.model3')->get();
```

But you data is not a chaining structure, so you can achieve it by :

```
Region::with('district')->with('ward')->get();
```

Or,

```
Region::with(['district', 'ward'])->get();
```